# Simple Script Engine template data type of a template function

Tags: c++, function, templates, typedef

I want to create a simple script engine.I declare a data struct.I has some variables.

```
enum DataType
{
DT_INT,
DT_FLOAT,
DT_BOOL,
DT_VOID,
DT_STRING
};

template < typename T > 
struct Data { 
  DataType data_type;
  std::string variable_name;
  T value; 

};
```

I declare types of data like that:

```
typedef Data< int > dataINT;
typedef Data< float > dataFLOAT;
typedef Data< bool > dataBOOL;
typedef Data< void > dataVOID;
typedef Data< std::string > dataSTRING;
```

I need a function gets template data of a template function.

```
    template < typename T >
    Data< T > getData< T >(std::string s);
```

And I create a function:

```
    typedef Data< int > getData< int > getDataINT(std::string s);//<---The compiler says :             "unrecognizable template declaration/definition"
```

I am stuck.What should I do?

Comment: Just drop the `typedef`.

Comment: should i use a something like that  :  Data<int> getData<int> getDataINT(std::string s);

Comment: By the way, you might want to read about [Boost variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/variant.html) and [Boost any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/any.html).

Comment: Also, `Data<void>` will not work very well either.

Comment: what should i do for a void?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the function declarations are completely wrong, both of them, you could use specialization of the functions:

```
template < typename T >
Data< T > getData(std::string s);

template < >
Data< int > getData(std::string s);

template < >
Data< float > getData(std::string s);

// etc...
```

Comment: it worked.but i couldn't understand why you use" template < > "?

Comment: And how should be structre of a script engine?Can you advise some tips?